# Hibernate Error accessing field, mapping issues

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm trying to implement hibernate and am looking at one of my old projects which uses the annotations. I want to have a manytoone mapping. Here are the classes.

Class used to hold ListItems, keeps reference to all the items inside of it which I am trying to map right now.

See `private List<ListItem> listItems`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEMLIST")
public class ItemList {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private UUID listId;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ListTypes listType;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "itemList")
    private List<ListItem> listItems;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private int position;
```

ListItem class which keeps a reference to the list it's currently in.

See `private ItemList itemList;`

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "ITEMTYPE")
@Table(name = "LISTITEM")
public abstract class ListItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private UUID itemId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private ItemList itemList;
    private String url;
    private String name;
    private Date dateAdded;
    private int position;
```

Test code used to test persistence:

```
    public ItemList createList(){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        ItemList itemList = new ItemList();
        session.save(itemList);
        factory.close();
        return itemList;
    }
```

Which gives me this error log:

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.util.List<xxx.listorganizer.listorganizer.Interfaces.ListItem> xxx.listorganizer.listorganizer.Models.ItemList.listItems] by reflection for persistent property [xxx.listorganizer.listorganizer.Models.ItemList#listItems] : xxx.listorganizer.listorganizer.Models.ItemList@7955d081
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.getForInsert(GetterFieldImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:570)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5170)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:618)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:606)
    at xxx.listorganizer.listorganizer.DAOs.ListDAO.createList(ListDAO.java:21)
    at xxx.listorganizer.listorganizer.ListorganizerApplication.main(ListorganizerApplication.java:14)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.List field xxx.listorganizer.listorganizer.Models.ItemList.listItems to xxx.listorganizer.listorganizer.Models.ItemList
    at ...
```

Hopefully someone can help :)

Comment: After commenting out the list part I tried running the code again and it gives me the same error for the ListTypes enum variable. Seems like it has to do with something other than just the List initially mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it had to do with me using UUID for the id generation. Changing this to a long fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not able to create  object of your abstract class